iOS missing Document file in the xcappdata file
The issue of missing Document file in the xcappdata file for an iOS project running on the App, Xcode 16 ,Has anyone encountered this problem? thank you
enter image description here
enter image description here
I think it's a configuration problem, but I have no idea

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Fixed. I think it's an iOS18 code execution bookorder problem

